# Noob question- PI wont boot

Tags: raspbian

I have a RPi Model B, and the green LED is just a small dot. I have already checked all the steps at http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting, but none work.

Any tips?

Comment: What output do you get if you connect it to a monitor?

Comment: @Bex Isn't it likely that he already had it connected to a monitor?

Comment: What is the voltage measured between TP1 and TP2? [help](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems)

Comment: Is it working yet?

Comment: I did connect it to a tv using the tv-out. No signal is what my TV says. Not working yet. Voltage between TP1 and TP2 is 4.99V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical pins on the SD card slot were mangled beyond repair. I need to solder another SD card  holder.

Looks like that was the problem

Comment: Would be most helpful if you mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your SD card's image is not correct.  If you have a Pi that boots correctly, try its card.  If not, try rebuilding the image.

I don't know what version of Linux you're trying to use, so I don't know the specifics.  But you might be able to take your SD card and mount it in an OS that can read it and look at the /var/log/dmesg.log or maybe /var/log/boot.msg on the card.  You should be able to find the boot messages if the boot process even starts.

Comment: Using Windows, and used the Win32DiskImager utility to loadup the SD card. I used "Run as Admin.." option while starting the program.

Answer (score 2):

Since your LED is 'just a small dot' it could be that you have a faulty power source. Try a different power cable (a Blackberry charger is what I use) and test your current power source on a different device.

If that doesn't work, then you probably have something wrong with either your Pi or your SD card (as mention in another answer).

Are you sure you've gone through everything because [this](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Pi_boots_sometimes_but_not_always) sounds awfully like your problem...

Comment: Voltage between Tp1 and Tp2 is 4.99V. I suspect the SD card to be faulty, but when I tried using an SD card from my camera, it still did not boot.

Comment: @Rupin Might be your image... What are you using? NOOBS or just plain Raspbian Wheezy?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of the answers from Paxton Sanders and user12321. I would try a different power source (I use an iPhone charger with a micro usb cable) and a different image on another SD card. You can get a number of different images for your SD card here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Using a process of elimination you can identify the fault, and then rectify it.